# Cypress can't access a website from its automated browser (used to work normally and other browsers access normally)

Tags: node.js, browser, automated-tests, cypress

I was hoping one of you could help me out here. I ran out of ideas already.

I have a script with Cypress.io that basically access a website and clicks on a link for LOGIN. I have reduced the code to only access the LOGIN page directly, which was working perfectly for the past 1-2 months, but in the past week I ran the script and it's no longer working.

When it tries to access the URL https://sso.tce.sp.gov.br/cas-server/login it gives the error below.

The most weird thing is that I can access this URL manually from the other non-automated (EDGE, Chrome), but when I try to do it with the Cypress automated browser it doesn't work.

> cy.visit() failed trying to load:
>
> https://sso.tce.sp.gov.br/cas-server/login
>
> We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request
> failed without a response.
>
> We received this error at the network level:
>
> > Error: Parse Error: Duplicate Content-Length
>
> Common situations why this would fail:
>
> - you don't have internet access
> - you forgot to run / boot your web server
> - your web server isn't accessible
> - you have weird network configuration settings on your computer

Apparently it's doesn't look like a proxy thing nor a code thing, do you guys have any idea of what it could be?

Code:

```
describe('Test', () => {


  it('Access AUDESP Website', function () {
        Cypress.config('chromeWebSecurity',false);
        //cy.visit('https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/audesp')
        //cy.get('.menu-superior-itens > [href="https://sso.tce.sp.gov.br/cas-server/login"]').click()



        cy.visit('https://sso.tce.sp.gov.br/cas-server/login')



    })
      })
```

Any ideas would be very helpful!!

Thank you!

UPDATE:

Guys, I'm still with this error, but I have found out that the website is sending a duplicate header, but cypress is not able to process it. The browser, outside of Cypress, ignores it apparently... any ideas on how to fix it on Cypress?

[image]